# Adjusting for timezone and daylight saving time on a per-user basis

Tags: mysql, api

I am doing an application where the users store their timezone in an SQL database.

How do I keep track when there is daylight saving time in their locations?

I was thinking of having a column in the users table with the users specified time zone, and then another table where i would match the user time zone with it's corresponding interval displacement regarding UTC

But how do I do a script that automatically changes this off set for places where there is daylight saving time? There are even places when sometimes there is daylight saving and some years there is not.

Should I use an API? If so, which one?

Is my appoach plain wrong?

Thank you

Comment: You should show us what you have done so far, not just ask for what to do. Here in SO we help people to fix mistakes.

Comment: I think the manual covers this one

Comment: @Phiter, what I have done so far is add a varchar column in my users table where i will store the time_zone as a string. Then a different table where for each time zone there will be the amount i need to add or substract from UTC. How do i update this table when time chages due to daylight savings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reinventing the wheel, here.

MySQL Server has built-in time zone handling capabilities, including the ability to "know" when and where it's daylight time (or not) from your system's time zone tables.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time-zone-support.html

The [`CONVERT_TZ()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz), embedded in a query, will convert a datetime from its current time zone (which you specify) into another one (the user's time zone).

> How do i update this table when time chages due to daylight savings

You don't.  If you have the correct time zone selected for the user, the daylight saving time conversion is handled automatically.

For example, converting a winter-time and a summer-time from UTC into the America/New_York time zone (Eastern Standard/Eastern Daylight).  Note the 5-hour (winter) vs 4-hour (summer) offset:

```
mysql> select convert_tz('2015-01-01 00:00:00','UTC','America/New_York');
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| convert_tz('2015-01-01 00:00:00','UTC','America/New_York') |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2014-12-31 19:00:00                                        |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select convert_tz('2015-06-01 00:00:00','UTC','America/New_York');
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| convert_tz('2015-06-01 00:00:00','UTC','America/New_York') |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2015-05-31 20:00:00                                        |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```